# Element inside modal not responding to click event

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, click

I have a modal in my angular app, but the elements in the modal are not responding to click event

Template

```
<div class='modal_wrapper centered top'>
 <div class ="row">
    <div class ="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11"></div>
     <div class ="red link right fs22 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" title ="Close Modal" (click) ="closeModal();">X</div>
 </div>

 <div id ="modal_content" class='modal_content' style ="background: yellow;">
   content
 </div>
</div>

  <p class ="test hide">
    <span (click)="hi();" style ="background: blue;">click me</span>
  </p>

  <br />
  <a (click)="doToggle('.test');" class='button glyphicon glyphicon-plus'>Click to toggle2</a>
```

Here is the TS class

```
export class AppComponent {
 constructor(private element: ElementRef){}

 doToggle(contentSelector){
   const modalTarget: HTMLElement = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.modal_wrapper');
   document.querySelector('.modal_wrapper .modal_content').innerHTML =    document.querySelector(contentSelector).innerHTML

   modalTarget.classList.toggle('active');
 }

 hi(){
   alert('hi')
 }

  }
```

When I click on the element inside the modal, I expect to see an alert but its not working. Can anyone help me out on what I need to do. Below is the output modal

[image]

Here is a link to try it on stackbliz https://angular-ivy-h6wmdb.stackblitz.io

Comment: Not sure why its not working, I have just created a stackblitz of your code and its working fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xezwym

Comment: @Loser thanks for your answer, but what you did on stackblitz is not in a modal. Secondly, the alert does not work when I click on the expected element in your work. Try click on the "click me" that is displayed when you toggle. It's not showing the alert

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz instance of your isssue ?

Comment: @Loser thanks for your responses. I've created it on stackbliz. https://angular-ivy-h6wmdb.stackblitz.io  You will notice that the alert does not come up when you click on "Click me to alert hi" inside the modal

Comment: I am not able to see the code in that stackblitz